# Official detailed documentation on changes in between Android versions?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-version

What I'm looking for specifically is Bluetooth between Ice Cream Sandwich and Jelly Bean.

Apparently, what is mentioned [here](http://www.android.com/about/jelly-bean/) or [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html) is not enough. For example, during the pairing process with a Bluetooth device (not an Android phone), Jelly Beans prompts you to confirm the pairing PIN but ICS does not.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are looking for this:

[Android API Differences Report 16](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/16/changes.html)